# CSS link navigation browser compatibility

Tags: css, linked-list, cross-browser

I have a horizontal linked list (implemented to look like tabs) that I'm using for a site navigation.

I checked my page today on my phone, and it didn't display correctly on Opera or in Internet Explorer.  I checked Internet Explorer 6 when I got home, and it appears the same way.

**HTML**

```
<div id="navcontainer"><ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="" id="current">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Referances</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Fun</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navcontainer>ul{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 0;
}

#navcontainer>ul>li {
    display: inline;
}

#navcontainer>ul>li>a {
    padding: 3px 0.5em;
    margin-left: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #778;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: #bbd;
}

#navcontainer>ul>li>a:hover {
    background-color: #369;
}

#navcontainer>ul>li>a#current {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

What is the best way to change this so it is more browser compliant?

Comment: Is the lack of a closing angle bracket on the first div just a typo?

Comment: With Google dropping support for IE6, I can finally agree with everyone that has been screaming the same thing for the last year. **Internet Explorer 6 is dead**. Drop support for it as the cost of building a site that conforms to its rendering is far greater than the rewards.

Comment: @ John it looks correct to me.  Is the ID throwing you off?
@ Andrew, yeah but i'm surprised to see that the browsers on my new phone did the same thing so I was wondering how much of a 'problem' it is.

Comment: I fixed it for you, Bolt_Head :)

Comment: ohh lmao.  It was a typo but it was on my page cause I copied the code and changed what you suggested below.  That "fixed" it except the div seems to not cover all the vertical space it should be.  Thanks

Comment: @Bolt head:  don't leave a space between the `@` and the name if you want them notified of your comment so they can retort.

Comment: You must also assign a fixed height to your `ul` of `div.navcontainer` now since floats will not increase the height of their container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE6 doesn't like `display:inline` very much.  Try `float:left` on both your `li`s and your `li a`.

Also, IE6 does not support the `>` child selector.

Answer (score 1):

For one, Internet Explorer 6 doesn't support the immediate child selector (>) that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

For the li items you should set:

```
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here was this?

```
<div id="navcontainer"<ul>
 <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Projects<a href="" id="current">Resume/a></li>
 <li><a href="">Referances<a href="">Fun
```

Which should be

```
<div id="navcontainer"><ul>
 <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Projects<a href="" id="current">Resume/a></li>
 <li><a href="">Referances<a href="">Fun
```